# How can I type cygwin sort with -S option?

Tags: sorting, cygwin

What is the syntax for -S option in sort? `with capital S`
I try:

```
sort -S filename
```

it gives me invalid argument!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation

> ```
> -S, --buffer-size=SIZE
>               use SIZE for main memory buffer
> ```

you should provide a number to the `-S` option. It also wokrs with human readable units like 8k, 2m, 1g.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I were using: '-S k 1024' by following the documentation: 'SIZE may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes:
% 1% of memory, b 1, K 1024 (default), and so on for M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y.
'